# Error while instaling Open GRM thrax

Tags: c++, ubuntu-14.04, text-mining, text-analysis, openfst

I have already installed Open Fst in Ubuntu and its working fine. Now i'm trying to install Open GRM thrax. I have tried installing with 2 different versions of thrax.

Thrax version 1.1.0:

```
thraxOpenGrm/thrax-1.1.0$ ./configure
```

below is the error that i get.

```
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for bison... no
checking for byacc... no
checking for std::tr1::hash<long long unsigned>... yes
checking for __gnu_cxx::slist<int>... yes
checking fst/fst.h usability... yes
checking fst/fst.h presence... no
configure: WARNING: fst/fst.h: accepted by the compiler, rejected by the preprocessor!
configure: WARNING: fst/fst.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for fst/fst.h... yes
checking fst/extensions/far/far.h usability... yes
checking fst/extensions/far/far.h presence... no
configure: WARNING: fst/extensions/far/far.h: accepted by the compiler, rejected by the preprocessor!
configure: WARNING: fst/extensions/far/far.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for fst/extensions/far/far.h... yes
checking fst/extensions/pdt/pdt.h usability... no
checking fst/extensions/pdt/pdt.h presence... no
checking for fst/extensions/pdt/pdt.h... no
configure: error: fst/extensions/pdt/pdt.h header not found
```

Thrax version 0.1.0:

```
thraxOpenGrm/thrax-0.1.0$ ./configure
```

below is the error that i get.

```
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for bison... no
checking for byacc... no
checking for std::tr1::hash<long long unsigned>... yes
checking for __gnu_cxx::slist<int>... yes
checking fst/fst.h usability... no
checking fst/fst.h presence... no
checking for fst/fst.h... no
configure: error: fst/fst.h header not found
```

It throws different errors with different thrax versions. I read a solution in this forum.

http://www.openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/Forum/GrmThraxForum

It says openfst must be 'built' with `./configure --enable-far=true` . i uninstalled openfst and installed it using `./configure --enable-far=true` and also with `./configure --enable-far`. The error still persists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

During installation of openfst you have to type:

```
./configure --enable-far=true --enable-pdt=true --enable-mpdt=true
```

Then you should install thrax and while on it, type in terminal:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

Worked for me for openfst-1.5.4 and thrax-1.2.2.

When I got:

```
checking fst/extensions/pdt/pdt.h usability... no
```

I added:

```
--enable-pdt=true
```

to `./configure` for openfst and I did the same for mpdt error. If you get other errors, you can try doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

if you specify ./configure --enable-far=true, it should work. Because it will install fst folder under /usr/local/include (you should run make install when install opengrm)

Answer (score 1):

then, you may come across error like: `fst/extensions/pdt/pdt.h header not found`

you can add --enable-pdt=true when ./configure opengrm

Answer (score 0):

I would try to remove openfst against and then do a find on the system to make sure all the fst/fst.h files are gone.  It might be missing something or some other package might have provided one.

Also, the --enable-far should not have =true on the end.   So, maybe try it that way.

Comment: I assume you don't just do a configure, but a 'make' and then 'make install' when installing openfst.

Comment: Just make and make install doesn't work. I tried it. ./configure is necessary.

Comment: Yes, you have to do all three.